# Excel to JSON conversion

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZKhV.png) excel file was converted to json,
but using pandas library in python it performs the conversion column wise and showed up like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQXab.png).
I want it to show up in the following format:

```
{"peopleInfo": [
{
  "Name": "John",
  "UserId": "39048",
  "FavoriteWords": [
    {
      "word": "Sincerity",
      "wordInfo": [
        {
          "meaning": "the quality or state of being sincere",
          "language": "English"
        },
        {
          "meaning": "honesty of mind",
          "language": "English"
        }, and so on....
      ]
    },
    {
      "word": "Sincerity",
      "wordInfo": [
        {
          "meaning": "the quality or state of being sincere",
          "language": "English"
        },
        {
          "meaning": "honesty of mind",
          "language": "English"
        }
      ]
    }, and so on....
  ]
},
{
  "Name": "Doe",
  "UserId": "23749",
  "FavoriteWords": [
    {
      "word": "Fun",
      "wordInfo": [
        {
          "meaning": "what provides amusement or enjoyment",
          "language": "English"
        },
        {
          "meaning": "a mood for find or making amusement",
          "language": "English"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "word": "Sharing",
      "wordInfo": [
        {
          "meaning": "to divide something between two or more people",
          "language": "English"
        },
        {
          "meaning": "joint use of a resource or space",
          "language": "English"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}, and so on....
```

]
}

Please don't consider the question's context, I know its lame but I'm working on something different.

Comment: You won't get that nested json format without some custom logic. If you wan't it to output a json array of one object for each row do `pandas.DataFrame.to_json(orient='records')`

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the .csv can be displayed as dictionary in python. As a file you can either use *nested .json* or .xml for this.

Nested .json from .csv can be generated with `csv.DictReader` like in [csv to nested JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969611/csv-to-nested-json)

`.json` is a serialization format, the structure of the .csv file is that of a *nested .json*, dictionary or .xml. To generate an .xml with  pandas use a module for `.xml` processing like `xml.etree.ElementTree`

https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-xml-files-in-python-with-pandas/

Also see this : **[How can I load a CSV file into a QTreeView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66041858/how-can-i-load-a-csv-file-into-a-qtreeview)**

[How to transform an XML file using XSLT in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698935/how-to-transform-an-xml-file-using-xslt-in-python)